# linq - retrieving data dependent on the object type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a structure like this

```
public class ItemBase 
{ 
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public ItemType Type { get; set; }
}

public class RockItem : ItemBase { }

public class PlantItem : ItemBase 
{ 
    public bool IsDeadly { get; set; }
}

public class AnimalItemBase : ItemBase 
{ 
    public int NumberOfLegs { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeadly { get; set; }
}

public class DogItem : AnimalItemBase { }

public class CatItem : AnimalItemBase { }
```

There is a type flag in the database and I use Fluent to split out on type and return an `IEnumerable<ItemBase>`

This works for most of what I want, but now I am in a situation where I need to meld the items together.  For instance, I want the `ItemId`, `IsDeadly`, and the `NumberOfLegs` returned in an anonymous object.  The results have to be sorted on the `Created` field in one list.  Is there an easy way to do this with linq?  Ideally, I would not have to split these out, merge the results, and then sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you give could be solved using `OfType`:

```
IEnumerable<ItemBase> items = ...
var results = items.OfType<AnimalItemBase>()
                   .OrderBy(x => x.Created).ToList();
```

If you have to support combinations of properties that cross classes i.e all items that have the `IsDeadly` property, you could use a combination of reflection to check the properties you want to use and `dynamic` to enable the [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) you need, since technically these are different `IsDeadly` properties, you just *know* they should be treated the same in your scenario.

Doing that you can then assign the properties in your anonymous type dynamically. I.e. the following example returns results for all of your types that have the `IsDeadly` property:

```
var results = items.OrderBy(x => x.Created)
                   .Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("IsDeadly") !=null)
                   .Select( x => 
                    {
                      dynamic o = x;
                      return new { IsDeadly = o.IsDeadly, Created = o.Created }; 
                    })
                   .ToList();
```

Also as @Henk Holterman pointed out, it only makes sense to return an enumeration of anonymous types where each property of the returned type makes sense / is defined for **all** the items in the enumeration.